# Grouping output with SQL across multiple fields

Tags: sql, date, group-by, sum, pivot

Starting with a simple table that contains

Date,Result,Account

where there can be more than one entry for a date&account combination and where there are some dates without entries for all accounts.

I'd like to output:

Date, Account1 sum(Result), Account2 sum(Result), etc...

In cases where there is data for one Account but not another Account for a certain date, I want to ensure there is still an entry for that date.   Currently my query does the above but only creates an entry when there is a value stored for all Accounts selected.

```
Select a.Date
,isnull(Sum(a.Result),0) as Total_Account1
,isnull(Sum(b.Result),0) as Total_Account2
From MyTable a
join MyTable b on a.Date = b.Date
Where a.Account = 'Account1'
and b.Account = 'Account2'
Group by a.Date,b.Date
Order By a.Date
```

Comment: what database are you using

Comment: why don't union both tables so you get all the dates and then group by . Use case statement to sum by account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend conditional aggregation rather than a self-join. It properly handles the dates when not both accounts are available, and will be more efficient since you don't need to scan the table twice:

```
select
    date,
    sum(case when account = 'Account1' then result else 0 end) total_account_1,
    sum(case when account = 'Account2' then result else 0 end) total_account_2
from mytable
where account in ('Account1', 'Account2')  -- this might not be necessary
group by date
```

The above query uses a SQL syntax that is supported by most databases, with `case` expression in the aggregate functions. Depending on your actual database (which you did not disclose), neater options may be available.